# How to colour specific characters of a part of tkinter listbox

Tags: python, tkinter, colors, listbox

I am making a way to search a listbox for items. I have bound the `<Key>` event to a function (so it runs whenever someone types in the search bar)

Here is my function:

```
def search(self):
            items = self.song_listbox.get(0, tk.END)
            print(items)
            new_items = []
            for item in items:
                if search_term in item.upper():
                    new_items.append(item)
            self.song_listbox.delete(0, tk.END)
            print(new_items)
            for item in new_items:
                self.song_listbox.insert(tk.END, item)
```

As you can see here, this will filter the listbox to only the items that contain the search terms.

What I want to do is highlight the characters in the listbox label that contain the search term. For example,

If the search term was `He` and there was an item `Hello` in the listbox, I'd want to colour the item like this:

`[He]llo` # Where inside [] is a certain colour

is this possible and how can I do this?

Comment: I don't think that's possible with a listbox, you can only change the color of the whole item.

Comment: can you please write the whole working code